# 'QString' object has no attribute 'strip'?

Tags: python, pyqt

So I'm trying to read a web page using mechanize.Browser() module in Python. The problem is that br.open(url) does not work, because python returns the error in the title.

Here's the code:

```
url = "http://www.myserver.com/prda.php?validate=" + licensey
readurl = br.open(url).read()
```

At the latter line, I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1038, in unwrap
url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I tried using unicode(readurl), unicode (br.open(url).read()), readlines() instead of read(), str (in place of unicode)... I either get the same error, or None output from br.open.read()

Help?

Comment: Any chance `licensey` is a QString?

Comment: Are you sure that you're showing us all the code?  Is `licensey` a `QString` or other string-like but not really string object?

Comment: Ha, thanks to both of you guys. licensey was indeed a QString. After doing str(licensey), the program worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can answer and accept that, otherwise it will stay an open question. :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are developing a PyQt application and 'licensey' is a input you are taking from some 'QTextEdit' element.

In your application the 'url' is of type 'QString'. And there is no 'strip' method in 'QString' data type. Since open() method expects you to send a parameter of type 'str', you just need to typecast the variable 'url'.

Just add the line

```
url = str(url)
```

before calling the method open(url). Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It is really strange that PyQt QString does not includes a strip() method, but it has a trimmed() method which does the same. See here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html#trimmed. What are really lacking in PyQt are the variants lstrip() and rtrip().