# python, script runs in spyder but not in console, BeautifulSoup failure

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spyder

I was trying to scrape some web contents. While the script runs fine in spyder python console (not ipython console), it throws an error when running in windows cmd line.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()
    self.app.quit()

url = "http://www.shfe.com.cn/en/MarketData/dataview.html?paramid=dailystock"
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
```

This is the error message

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 225, in __init__
markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 118, in prepare_markup
for encoding in detector.encodings:
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 257, in encodings
self.markup, self.is_html)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 319, in find_declared_encoding
declared_encoding = declared_encoding_match.groups()[0].decode(
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (32-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:36:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: This may be helpful: [attributeerror-qstring-object-has-no-attribute-rfind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263086/attributeerror-qstring-object-has-no-attribute-rfind)

Comment: interesting... `BeautifulSoup(unicode(result), 'lxml')` worked! Thanks.